# Count how many different final position are there?

Tags: combinatorics, coordinate-systems

A frog started from the origin of the coordinate plane and made three jumps. Each time the frog jumped a distance of 5 units and landed at a point with integer coordinate. How many different possibilities of the final position of the frog are there?

I've tried to write some programs to calculate it, on khanAcademy:
https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/speed-optimization-of-happy-frog-jumping-everywhere/5425374405623808
and the result of each jumps is given like this: 12 73 264 553 916,

also I notice that the final position of the frog forms a decagon on the coordinate plane.

Thus, I know that the answer is 264, but I want to know what is the method to count it by hand?

Comment: For anyone interested, this is taken from the [2018 IMO preliminary contest](https://www.hkage.org.hk/file/competitions/4287/Prelim2018.pdf) in Hong Kong, question 19.

Comment: I think your program is wrong – if the frog jumps once I found 8 possibilities, and if the frog jumps twice I found 33 possibilities using [GeoGebra](https://www.geogebra.org/graphing/bzdpa2tg).

Comment: @TobyMak you forgot $(5,0)$

Comment: @Empy2 How can you get to that point?

Comment: @TobyMak the first jump can get to (5,0) (-5,0) ... I missed it too because I was thinking Pythagorean triplets

Comment: @jwc845 Oh yeah! Thanks for telling me.

Comment: The answer is indeed 264. [Here](https://web2.0calc.com/api/ssl-img-proxy?src=%2Fimg%2Fupload%2F81f61aaba3eaf8684d45501d%2Fl1.png) are all the 264 points, from [this thread](https://web2.0calc.com/questions/some-algebra-questions).